# Insert empty params into decimal nullable columns

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have no values to insert into MaxPrice or MinPrice columns which can be null.  The values when they don't exist are originally were seen as , , in the resulting Sql expression.  I got a syntax error before and changed the code to this

```
 (setItem.MinPrice.ToString()!="")?setItem.MinPrice.ToString() : null,
 (setItem.MaxPrice.ToString() != "") ? setItem.MaxPrice.ToString() : null
```

But when I execute this I get an error and the sql still looks like the , , .  The columns are decimal but can be NULL.

Comment: You're doing string concatenation to build your SQL and `null` does not add anything to a string. Instead, you should use parameters and pass `null` for the parameter values. There are numerous problems with your code so you should not use string concatenation for this.

Comment: You can also just use `"null"` instead of `null`, but using parameters is definitely the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameters. Always.

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minPrice",
    setItem.MinPrice == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)setItem.MinPrice);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@maxPrice",
    setItem.MaxPrice == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)setItem.MaxPrice);
```

or with a tool like Dapper:

```
// adds "@MinPrice" and "@MaxPrice" correctly as parameters, as long
// as the sql contains those tokens in some way
conn.Execute(sql, new { setItem.MinPrice, setItem.MaxPrice });
```

The **bad** fix - do not use - would be to supply the literal `"null"` in your concatenation. There are many many reasons not to do this:

```
// bad code; do not use
(setItem.MinPrice.ToString() != "") ? setItem.MinPrice.ToString() : "null",
(setItem.MaxPrice.ToString() != "") ? setItem.MaxPrice.ToString() : "null"
```

Comment: An additional reason not to use the string expressions is that `.ToString()` will not be a good solution for cultures that use comma as decimal separator, but that's just icing on the cake really.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen yes, one of many - and I very nearly added an invariant fix, but ... I don't really want to start going into all that, really. There's so many reasons *not* to do that - it seems hard to choose a favorite :)